# Death Angels - Is the Force Field Overpowered?

Tags: balance, death-angel

We've been playing the new Space Hulk card game, "Death Angels" at our gaming sessions of late.  We've noticed that the Force Field card (the Librarian Support) seems to be a game-winner, to the extent that our strategies revolve around it 100% when it is available.  Since it can shut down a single swarm of an arbitrarily large size, and since swarms move collectively and merge when they arrive at the same square, our tactics tend to center around herding all the swarms onto a single square, then using "Force Field" infinitely to lock it down while we move through the Hulk at will and eventually reach the last room.

Upon reaching the last room, frequently the objective has nothing to do with killing all the 'stealers, so we auto-win.  On the few occasions where it does require killing all the stealers, the location card itself frequently provides an out, or we stack all of our support tokens on the librarian and have him 'chain-gun' the swarm down.

The card itself seems to have robbed the game of much of its challenge. Is this correct, or are we missing something about how the card works and how its mechanics interact with the game?

Comment: Perhaps "20 support tokens" was just an exaggeration, but there are only 12 support tokens available (Component Limitations, p30 of the rule book).

Comment: Yea, "like 20" was a bit of hyperbole.  Busted ;(

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> A player may *not* chose an Action card that he resolved during the previous game round (pg11 of the [Rule Book](http://www.fantasyflightgames.com/ffg_content/death-angel/minisite/support/death-angel-rulebook-web.pdf))

Given that rule, how can you use **Force Field** indefinitely?

Comment: ...by overlooking that rule.  Oh geez, that changes things dramatically.